# How to scale axes in tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to scale my drawing without distorting the graph and the text within the plot.

My current code shows the drawing in 1:1 scale. What I want is to show it in a rectangular scale.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.5]
      \begin{semilogyaxis}[
          width=\linewidth, % Scale the plot to \linewidth
          grid style={dashed,gray!60},
          ylabel=Y Axis $I$,
          y unit=mV,
          legend style={at={(1,1)},anchor=north east},
          xticklabels={,,}
        ]
        \addplot[smooth,color=orange,mark=x,thick] 
        table[x=index,y=data,col sep=semicolon] {C2W8.csv};
        \addplot[smooth,color=blue,mark=*,thick] 
        table[x=index,y=data,col sep=semicolon] {C2W16.csv};
        \legend{8-way,16-way}
      \end{semilogyaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{My first autogenerated plot.}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `height=0.5\linewidth`?

Comment: That was what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified the width of the plot with `width=\linewidth`. You can specify the height the same way, so for example `height=0.5\linewidth` in the axis options will give a figure with a height that is half the width.

(I don't have your data files of course, so I replaced them with simple exponentials.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{semilogyaxis}[
          width=\linewidth, % Scale the plot to \linewidth
          height=0.5\linewidth,   % <-- this line is new
          grid style={dashed,gray!60},
          ylabel=Y Axis $I$,
          y unit=mV,
          legend style={at={(1,1)},anchor=north east},
          xticklabels={,,}
        ]
        \addplot[smooth,color=orange,mark=x,thick] {exp(x)};
        \addplot[smooth,color=blue,mark=*,thick] {exp(2*x)};
        \legend{8-way,16-way}
      \end{semilogyaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{My first autogenerated plot.}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```